# Filtro de busca com web service

Tags: php

Preciso de um filtro de busca de acordo com a `data` para um extrato. no entanto esses dados vem de um web service.

```
echo "<table>";
foreach($resposta->lancamentos->lancto as $info) {
echo   "<tr> 
            <td>$info->descricao</td>
            <td>$info->dt_lancto</td>
            <td>$info->valor</td>
        </tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

como poss fazer esse sisteminha galera? é possível?

Comment: Como esses dados são obtidos e existe um campo que define tal data ?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic são obtidos através do resultado da consulta do web service.

Comment: se tem como dar um `var_dump($resposta->lancamentos->lancto);` e dizar qual dos campos quer a pesquisa é qual é a pesquisa?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não entendi exatamente onde adiciono esse trexo do código. meu código irá retornar um extrato de compras e quero colocar um campo de filtro. para a pessoa ver o extrato de acordo com a data que ela escolher no filtro de buscas